# I can't track down this leak. Audio Toolbox

Tags: cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I have gone over a silly amount of forum posts and questions here. while i would love to take this advice: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2003 I suppose i just don't trust 'them' as much as this community.

so, I ask, is this a 'negligible leak' if it only seems to happen once when i push a view onto the root view controller?

[image: image from Instruments]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core audio libraries have always given me unfixable memory leaks. Just ignore them because they are Apple's fault.

There's 416 bytes leaked there but if it only happens once then it's nothing to worry about.

With my code, the AVAudioPlayer class leaks each time I call the play method. It's rubbish. Luckily it's only a small leak.

Comment: Thank you. It is pretty hard not to hunt that white whale.

Comment: Though a lot of search, your answer make me feel comfort.